# How can I refactor away this repeated series of "if" blocks?

Tags: perl

I smell something bad here?

```
    if ($col == 24) {
        $buffer{'Y'} = trim($val);
        return;
    }

    if ($col == 25) {
        $buffer{'Z'} = trim($val);
        return;
    }

    if ($col == 26) {
        $buffer{'AA'} = trim($val);
        return;
    }

    if ($col == 27) {
        $buffer{'AB'} = trim($val);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: One other thing: I 'smell' some excel automation in there (column Z to AA ... hmm!) Likely you want the named column for a particular column number.  Definately look at Tanktalus's answer too.

Comment: This should go on the dailyWTF. It stinks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The names look suspicious, too.  If you're looping through the columns, try the magic ++ operator.

```
my $colname = 'A';
for (0..$#cols)
{
   # do stuff with $colname
   $buffer{$colname} = trim($val);
   ++$colname;
}
```

If not, there does seem to be a pattern here that you can exploit for converting numbers from decimal (digital) to alphabetic.  You'd do it the same way you'd convert a digital number to decimal, except that you'd use characters A-Z, base 26, instead of 0-9, base 10.  Something like:

```
sub colname
{
  my $num = shift;
  my $name = '';
  while ($num)
  {
    $name .= chr(ord('A') + $num % 26);
    $num /= 26;
  }
  reverse $name;
}
```

(untested)  This algorithm is language-neutral.  It doesn't particularly take advantage of perlishness, but works wonderfully as a general-case.

**Update**: I told you this was untested.  j_random_hacker pointed out the thinko, and I've corrected it.  Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that last line read "reverse $name;"? Otherwise good.

Answer (score 12):

Associative arrays work well in these cases.  First initialize:

```
my %colToBuffer = ( 24 => 'Y', 25 => 'Z', 26 => 'AA', 27 => 'AB');
```

Then the code can be:

```
if (exists $colToBuffer{$col})
{
    $buffer{$colToBuffer{$col}} = trim($val);
}
```

Season to taste.

Comment: +1, very concise! Although, probably not too good if you have to initialise a lot of values.

Comment: I typed up the equivalent, but in Python since I don't know Perl.  I'll just +1 you instead.

Answer (score 2):

Find a way to encode "$col" into a string that represents that column in the hash (i.e. turns 25 into 'Z' and 26 into 'AA' etc).

```
sub encodeCol {
  ...
}

$buffer{encodeCol($col)} = trim($val);
```

Answer (score 1):

If $col is in 24..27, then calculate the corresponding letter, and set the proper hash entry.  Here are two ways to do it, depending on whether you want to save a few characters or save a few bytes:

```
24 <= $col && $col <= 27 and $buffer{('A'..'AB')[$col]} = trim($val);
```

or

```
24 <= $col && $col <= 27 and $buffer{('Y'..'AB')[$col - 24]} = trim($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

In other programming languages, you'd use a switch statement.  [This page](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-switch.html) has several ways to emulate a switch statement in Perl (5+).

Of course, if I had bothered to read the question closely, I wouldn't have suggested a switch statement for handling a specific *sequence* of inputs to outputs.

Comment: perl 5.10.x has default switch (use Switch.pm for older version). But switch statement, imho, is just same ugly as repeated if - only looks cleaner.

Comment: There's no need for a switch statement here, since every option does the same basic thing.  As George Phillips demonstrated, a hash works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In C-like pseudocode, to encode the column numbers:

```
alphabet[1:26] = {'A','B','C','D',...,'Z'}
col = col + 1; // so that 1=A, ..., 26=Z
string = "";

while(col > 0) {
    letterRank = col % 26; // % for modulo
    string = concatenate(alphabet[letterRank], string);
    col = col / 26; // integer division
}
```